# Ignore "joined the Hangout" notifications

Tags: notifications, google-hangouts

I am in a Google Hangout conversation.

All messages are interesting, so I enabled notifications.

Unfortunately, many people join and leave (more than actual messages), and I receive a notification each time.

**Question**: How to disable Google Hangout notifications for join/leave events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no option to disable/ignore only "joined/left the Hangout" notifications.